# Procedimiento almacenado con variable y valores separados por coma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Les cuento, tengo este SP por medio del cual necesito hacer un insert a una tabla a partir de un valor (@idperiodo) y varios campos separados por coma, mismos que he metido en la variable "Nominas".

La consulta asociada a la variable: `select Nomina from ADC_Vista_UnRengP`
devuelve un solo campo con varios valores separados por coma con comilla siemple cada uno, algo como esto: 'JARDINERIA','LIMPIEZA','MANTENIMIENTO'

Si pruebo el insert por separado, es decir sin estar dentro del SP me funciona perfectamente, pero al agregarlo al SP no me devuelve ningún valor. Sospecho que el error está en la forma como estoy agregando los valores separados por coma a la variable. Este es mi SP (cabe aclarar que al crearlo no me dio ningún problema) pero no funciona :/ ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
create proc insertaenM(
@Idperiodo int)
as
BEGIN
    declare @Nominas nvarchar(max)=(select Nomina from ADC_Vista_UnRengP);
    INSERT INTO ADC_M(campoextra1, descripcion, tipoconcepto, Importe)
    select e.campoextra1
          , c.descripcion,
            case when c.tipoconcepto='P' 
                then 0 
                else 1 
            end as tipoconcepto
          , sum(h.importetotal) as Importe 
          from nom10007 AS h 
            inner join nom10034 AS e on h.idempleado=e.idempleado 
                                and h.idperiodo=e.cidperiodo 
            inner join nom10004 AS c on h.idconcepto=c.idconcepto 
    where h.idperiodo=@Idperiodo 
        and e.campoextra1 in(@Nominas) 
        and importetotal<>0 
    group by e.campoextra1
           , c.descripcion
           , c.tipoconcepto 
    order by e.campoextra1
            , c.descripcion;
END;

exec insertaenM 1032
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo tienes una variable como esta:

```
DECLARE @Nominas NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'JARDINERIA,LIMPIEZA,MANTENIMIENTO'
```

Y quieres seleccionar filas en función de que ciertas cadenas estén o no en este conjunto. Para esto simplemente usa `CHARINDEX()`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (  SELECT  'JARDINERIA' as campoextra1 UNION
            SELECT  'MANTENIMIENTO' UNION
            SELECT  'VENTA'
    ) T
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + T.campoextra1 +',', ',' + @Nominas + ',') > 0


campoextra1
--------------
JARDINERIA
MANTENIMIENTO
```

Lo que hacemos es ver si (por ejemplo) `,JARDINERIA,` se encuentra dentro de la cadena `,JARDINERIA,LIMPIEZA,MANTENIMIENTO,`. Agregamos comas para asegurar que no nos encuentre cadenas parciales dentro de una palabra compuesta, es decir no queremos que `JARDINERIA` coincida con `JARDINERIA y LIMPIEZA` por dar un ejemplo.

Para poder usar el `IN` deberías hacer un "split" de la variable `@Nominas` por la coma y transformar todo en una tabla, esto ya fue preguntado en la comunidad [ver búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20split)